# Revalidate after added .is-invalid class

Tags: jquery, validation

I am validating my inputs by adding class "is-invalid" to them by jquery's addClass().

Then trying to revalidate them upon change with:

```
 $(".mandatory.is-invalid").on("input", function() {
       console.log("revalidate...");       
       validate($(this))
       });
```

However i cannot find the .mandatory.is-invalid elements by their class...

Comment: When are you making this binding?  Before or after that invalid class is added?

Comment: It is done before, on page load.

Comment: So, at the time of page load, those elements will not hae the invalid class, so it will not matching on anything to bind on.  You need to change that to a delegate event listener